# Manter dados nos campos depois de uma ação ou atualização na página - PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de uma ajuda na seguinte questão. Quando eu selecionar um item num combobox (seria para um filtro de pesquisa), eu queria que este item continuasse selecionado depois de apertar o botão "Consultar".
Abaixo, segue uma parte do código. Se estiver faltando alguma informação, desculpe. É só falar , que eu forneço mais informações.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Sistema</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <select class="form-control" name="sistema">
           <option value="" >Todos</option>
           <?php
             $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sistema WHERE Codigo = 12 ORDER BY Descricao");
             while ($sistema = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo '<option value=' . $sistema['Codigo'] . ' selected>' . $sistema ['Descricao'] . '</option>';
             }
             $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sistema WHERE Codigo <> 12 ORDER BY Descricao");
             while ($sistema = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo '<option value=' . $sistema['Codigo'] . '>' . $sistema['Descricao'] . '</option>';
             }
             ?>
           </select>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Porque tem 2 querys relacionados ao id 12 ? um = e outra diferente ? seria uma teste

Comment: O botão "Consultar" submete o formulário? E como é essa requisição, GET ou POST? Para qual URL?

Comment: Uma query serve pra deixar selecionado um sistema por default. A outra, mostra a lista de sistemas que estão no banco de dados.

Comment: é requisição POST.

Comment: Pra deixar um default você poderia colocar o html puro fora do loop, ou verificar dentro do loop se o sistema atual é o que você quer e deixar selecionado. ` ($sistema['Codigo'] == 12? 'selected':'')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O trecho `echo '<option '.( (!isset($_POST['sistema']) && $sistema['Codigo'] == 12) || (isset($_POST['sistema'] && $_POST['sistema'] == $sistema['Codigo'] ? 'selected' : '') ).'   value=' . $sistema['Codigo'] . '>' . $sistema['Descricao'] . '</option>';`

Verifica se o valor contido em `$_POST['sistema']` é igual ao sistema atual ou, se não houver `$_POST['sistema']`,verifica se o sistema atual é o 12... Se uma destas for verdade, trará o valor selecionado.

Isso fará com que o ultimo valor pesquisado venha selecionado, e caso ainda não exista valor, trará o de Código 12

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Sistema</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <select class="form-control" name="sistema">
           <option value="" >Todos</option>
            <?php
             $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sistema WHERE Codigo <> 12 ORDER BY Descricao");
             while ($sistema = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo '<option '.( (!isset($_POST['sistema']) && $sistema['Codigo'] == 12) || (isset($_POST['sistema'] && $_POST['sistema'] == $sistema['Codigo'] ? 'selected' : '' ) ).'   value=' . $sistema['Codigo'] . '>' . $sistema['Descricao'] . '</option>';
             }
             ?>
           </select>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Valeu, amigo!! Deu certo!

Comment: Opa, disponha! Até mais.

Answer (score 1):

Criei as condições para que quando a variável `$_POST['sistema']:` existir e for igual ao id do Looping ou caso ela não exista e o id do looping for `12` a `option` fique como selected porem quando houver um `$_POST` valido ele selecione ele.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Sistema</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <select class="form-control" name="sistema">
           <option value="" >Todos</option>
           <?php
             $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sistema ORDER BY Descricao");
             while ($sistema = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                 if(
                     (isset($_POST['sistema']) == true && ($_POST['sistema'] == $sistema['Codigo'])) || (isset($_POST['sistema']) == false && ($sistema['Codigo'] == 12))){
                     echo '<option value=' . $sistema['Codigo'] . ' selected >' . $sistema ['Descricao'] . '</option>';
                 }else{
                    echo '<option value=' . $sistema['Codigo'] . ' >' . $sistema ['Descricao'] . '</option>';
                 }
             }             
             ?>
           </select>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show!! Deu certo aqui, amigo. Muito Obrigado!